# How to use have a single footnote for multiple markers?

Tags: footnotes, footmisc

I want to mark some of the items with a dagger, but have a single footnote text for them all. I have the following now:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\newcounter{daggerfootnote}
\newcommand*{\daggerfootnote}[1]{%
    \setcounter{daggerfootnote}{\value{footnote}}%
    \renewcommand*{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}%
    \footnote[2]{#1}%
    \setcounter{footnote}{\value{daggerfootnote}}%
    \renewcommand*{\thefootnote}{\arabic{footnote}}%
}
\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
    \item Test 1\daggerfootnote{Test footnote}
    \item Test 2
    \item Test 3\daggerfootnote{}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

The problem with this is that it puts multiple footnotes. However, I want to have a single footnote for all the places I mark with dagger. How can I achieve this?

Comment: How would be marked the usual footnotes, if any?

Comment: Looks like you maybe want `fixfoot` for the task. Or maybe `sepfootnotes`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second and further occurrence you can just print the dagger symbol as math superscript:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[height=5cm]{geometry}

\newcounter{daggerfootnote}
\newcommand*{\daggerfootnote}[1]{%
    \setcounter{daggerfootnote}{\value{footnote}}%
    \renewcommand*{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}%
    \footnote[2]{#1}%
    \setcounter{footnote}{\value{daggerfootnote}}%
    \renewcommand*{\thefootnote}{\arabic{footnote}}%
}
\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
    \item Test 1\daggerfootnote{Test footnote}
    \item Test 2
    \item Test 3${}^\dagger$
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]